# What does OMIT mean in a Go build constraint?

Tags: go

I found `// +build OMIT` in this page https://blog.golang.org/context/server/server.go

I know what a build constraint is.

`OMIT` isn't

1. a `GOOS` or `GOARCH` value
2. a compiler name
3. `cgo`
4. a term for each Go major release as `go1.12`
5. any additional tags given by the -tags flag

Does it literally mean "omit something here" as `// +build ignore` keeps a file from being considered for the build ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file is ignored when the the build tag `OMIT` is not specified. It works the same way as `ignore`. The `OMIT` and `ignore` tags have no special meaning to the build tools.

The file is included in the blog post using the [present](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/present) package [.code](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/present#hdr-Command_Invocations) command. The .code command ignores source file lines ending with `OMIT`.

In summary, two things are going on.  The build constraint is used to ignore the file. The tag `OMIT` is used instead of the more common `ignore` so that the build constraint does not appear in the blog post.

The program is run using `go run server.go`.  The `go run` command ignores build constraints.

Comment: Oh, I see. This program is just an example, we can run it using `go run`, but we're not supposed to build it using `go build`.